# Can't give a Local storage value in react

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I am making an email form that once it was submitted, I want to store a Boolean value to local storage that  make the visitors couldn't send multiple time. But instead I got a blank page and "undefined" value.

my Code
edit(I paste localStorage.getItem below setItem and It is worked)

```
import React,{useRef,useState,useEffect} from 'react'
      import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';


import './Style/Contact.css'
function Contact() {
const form = useRef();
const [isSubmited,setIsSubmited]= useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const Data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DoNotDisturb'));
  if (Data) {
   setIsSubmited(Data);
  }

},[])
useEffect(() => {
console.log(isSubmited)
localStorage.setItem('DoNotDisturb', JSON.stringify(isSubmited))
},[isSubmited])
const sendEmail = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
    setIsSubmited(true)

  emailjs.sendForm('Jeremy_kun', 'JeremyPortfolio', form.current, 
'0Vide87CskT8zVici')
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.text);
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error.text);
    });
};
return (
<div className='Contact'>

    <h1>Reach me out</h1>

   <form className='form' ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" />
  <label>Message</label>
  <textarea name="message"  />
  
  <input className='sendBtn' type= 'submit'  value="Send" />
   </form>
   <div className="ContactBottom"></div>
</div>
```

)
}

```
export default Contact;
```

Comment: Please paste code as text: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please read [ask], particularly the part about not posting images of code.

Comment: Having a look anyway, I don't think you're setting the item in localstorage anywhere

Comment: before parsing data using JSON add if condition to check if its undefined. for below line
`const Data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DoNotDisturb'));`

Answer (score 0):

"react": "^18.1.0"

I think that `localStorage.getItem("DoNotDisturb") = undefined` If don't have `DoNotDisturb`.

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("DoNotDisturb") as string);
```

[image]